# How to rewrite dynamic sub domain to path URI in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a requirement where `{any-dynamic-subdomain}.domain.com` should rewrite to  `domain.com/{any-dynamic-subdomain}` but not for `www.domain.com`

Example:

1. api.domain.com -> domain.com/api
2. api-1.domain.com -> domain.com/api-1

so on..

Note: Here subdomains are dynamic in nature.

Nginx version: openresty/1.11.2.2

Current nginx configs:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com;
    return       301 https://www.domain.in$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    set $upstream_endpoint backend-api.tools.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header HOST $upstream_endpoint;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_pass http://$upstream_endpoint;
    }
    ------------------------
}
```

Kindly advise Nginx configurations for the same. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use a named capture in the `server_name` directive:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    root /var/www/htmldoc;
    index index.htm index.html;
    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  ~^(?<name>[^\.]+)\.domain\.com$;
    set $upstream_endpoint backend-api.tools.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header HOST $upstream_endpoint;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_pass http://$upstream_endpoint/$name;
    }
    ------------------------
}
```

Comment: I tried this and working as expected but CSS pages are not loading properly. Getting error - domain.com/styles.e18bdea0fddcd9df4369.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.

Comment: Any other settings I need to include to handle css/js pages? @IVO GELOV

Comment: I believe that your backend is sending wrong Content-Type header - it is not nginX's fault.

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite to(proxy_pass http://$upstream_endpoint/$name) if the URL has no request_uri apart from / and anything in request_url rewrite to (proxy_pass http://$upstream_endpoint/)?

Comment: If you request `api-2.example.com/` it will go to `http://upstream/api-2/` but if you request `api-2.example.com/test.php` it will go to `http://upstream/api-2/test.php`

Comment: Yes, but I don't want api-2.example.com/test.php to go to http://upstream/api-2/test.php. How do I handle these in location settings? I tried the following, the browser works when I hit first time but next time it goes to www.domain.com.   server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  ~^(?<name>[^\.]+)\.domain\.com$;
    set $upstream_endpoint backend-tools.com;
    location = / {
       -----
        proxy_pass http://$upstream_endpoint/$name;
        
    }
    location / {
     -----
        proxy_pass http://$upstream_endpoint;
    }

Comment: You can not have duplicate `location` blocks. MY advice is to start by clearly defining (e.g. by writing down) what output should be produced for each of the possible inputs.

Comment: My home page CSS pages won't load properly if it goes to upstream/api-2/. The CSS files must be served from upstream/. Hence we want the home page served from upstream/api-2 and other pages from upstream/* to work correctly. Kindly suggest if this can be handled at Nginx or from the backend.

Comment: You can add `location` blocks that are more specific than `location /`